# Java map iteration

Tags: java, dictionary, conditional-statements, bayesian

I'd like to iterate over several entries in a map...

In `wizard()`, I put 4 mappings in `map`, and then send the map along with two inputs `cancer` and `test` to be calcuated...

```
public int wizard() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //historical data of having cancer given test result...

    map.put("+cancer", "+test");
    map.put("-cancer", "+test");
    map.put("-cancer", "-test");
    map.put("+cancer", "+test");

    String cancer = "+cancer";
    String test = "+test";

    //send historical data to be calculated...
    return calculate(cancer, test, map);
}
```

Here, `calcuate()` iterates through the map indices looking for matches to the two inputs `cancer` and `test`, and then returns the conditional probability:

```
public int calculate(String cancer, String test, Map<String, String> map) {
    int tests = 0;
    int both = 0;

    System.out.println("Cancer: " + cancer + "; Test: " + test);
    for (int i = 0; i <= map.size(); i++) {
        if (map.containsValue(test)) { 
            tests++;
            if (map.containsValue(cancer)) {
                both++;     
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("{Cancer & Tests}: " + both + "; Tests: " + tests);
    return both/tests;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Cancer: +cancer; Test: +test

{Cancer & Tests}: 0; {Tests}: 3

P(Cancer|Test): 0
```

You can see that `both++` is not incrementing (aka: `{Cancer & Tests}`: shouldn't be `0`), therefore `P(Cancer|Test)` is not giving the correct answer.

Why is this? Am I iterating incorrectly over the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a for loop ? I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. You should be looking for cancer in the "key".

It should have read

```
    if (map.containsKey(cancer)) {
    }
```

Other mysterious thing is :

> ```
>     map.put("-cancer", "+test");
>     map.put("-cancer", "-test");
> ```

Only the second entry is going to be there in the map. You are overwriting the first entry with the second one.

May be you could iterate the map like

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String entry = entry.getKey(), value = entry.getValue();
        //Do comparisons.
        //increment counter  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over the map, use `entrySet()`

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue().equals(test)) {
        tests++;
        if(entry.getKey().equals(cancer)) {
            both++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `containsValue` method looks at the values that are inside the map (second in `put`), but not the keys (first in `put`).  To determine if a *key* is in the map, use the `containsKey` method.

But not only are you iterating over the `Map` incorrectly, you're misusing it from the start.  A `Map` will not allow duplicate keys, because a key cannot map to more than one value.  So, your third and fourth calls to `put` overwrite the second and first keys, respectively.  You only have two entries.

I would create a `Pair` class to hold your "cancer" and your "result" values in the same object, and use `Pair` as the key to your map (don't forget to override `equals` and `hashCode` in `Pair`, so the `Map` works correctly).  The you could use a `Map<Pair, Integer>` that maps a specific combination to its count.  Before you call `put`, call `containsKey` to see if the `Pair` already exists, and if so, `put` the existing value plus 1, else put a value of 1.  Then, in `calculate`, you can `get` the counts of the `Pair` objects you're interested in.

To access the values, use the `entrySet` method to get a `Set` view of the entries in the `Map`.

Comment: Okay, well is there some other way to do an associative array, like: `$Data[0] = array("+cancer", "+test");`, `$Data[1] = array("-cancer", "-test");`? I'd just like to iterate through each portion of an associative array and see if those values are contained together at a specific array index.

Comment: I've amended my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
map.put("+cancer", "+test");
map.put("-cancer", "+test");
map.put("-cancer", "-test");
map.put("+cancer", "+test");
```

When you add `"+cancer"` or `"-cancer"` twice, the second time overwrites the first one.  A `Map` by definition can contain only one entry with a given key.  Each time you add a new entry with the same key you replace the previous entry.

Comment: Okay, well is there some other way to do an associative array, like: `$Data[0] = array("+cancer", "+test");`, `$Data[1] = array("-cancer", "-test");`? I'd just like to iterate through each portion of an associative array and see if those values are contained together at a specific array index.

Comment: A `Map` _is_ an associative array. If you want to associate _multiple values_ with a single key you need a `MultiMap`, which is not part of the standard Java collections, although there are several implementations available as open source libraries.